# эмулятор приставок на сайте

Tags: хостинг, эмулятор

как все вы знаете, в интернете существует множество сайтов, где можно поиграть онлайн в приставки (типа денди, сега). 
хочу установить у себя на сайте такой же эмулятор. 
но не могу найти в инете инструкций, как это сделать. 
подскажите, пожалуйста, тематические ресурсы, или статьи, как прикрутить на сайт эмулятор любой приставки. 
update. немного не понимаю, каких правок требует вопрос? 
есть хостинг. есть доменное имя. есть апач. есть php. всё настроено и работает. надо сделать так, чтобы при открытии site.ru/games открывался эмулятор, допустим сеги. и можно было бы играть онлайн в сеговские ромы, которые лежат в соседнем каталоге. ссылка на скачивание будет. будет эмулятор, будут и игры

Comment: Открываем гугл, пишем «js sega emulator», читаем